# Is there a (reusable) Android UI component for an URL input field supporting autocompletion and suggestions?

Tags: android, url, browser

I'm developing a browser application for Android 2.2. Of course, this application needs an UI element to enter a URL.
Is there a way to reuse UI components like those used in the default Android browser, Dolphin HD or Fennec? I do not want to rebuild all the features from scratch like
 - auto-completion / Suggestions from google
 - auto-selecting the domain name (without "www.")

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact behaviour of each input type, but maybe this will be a help: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

if you find a good type, please give a short feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I understand the android:inputType only defines the layout of the on-screen keyboard (which keys should be displayed). I'm using android:inputType="textUri" at the moment. But this attribute does not "activate" the required features like auto-completion of URLs.

Answer (score 2):

Now I've found an interesting thing: There is a widget called [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

You have to set an Adapter, which holds the available auto complete entries. If you catch the text change event, you only have to get the current input from the text view and implement a lookup for available URLs and add the result to the array adapater. These new entries gets displayed as the available auto completes of your current input.

The code can be something like this:

```
public class AutoCompleteTest
    extends Activity
    implements TextWatcher
{

private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(layoutRes);
    this.autoCompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(viewId);
    this.autoCompleteView.addTextChangedListener(this);
    this.autoCompleteView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence currentSubmission, final int start, final int before, final int count)
{
    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // your code for retrieving url for the current input
            // maybe a remote service request
            final String[] urls;

            final Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putStringArray("urls", urls);

            final Message msg = new Message();
            msg.setData(data);
            MultiTouchTest.this.messageHandler.sendMessage(new Message());
        }

    }.start();
}

public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s)
{
    //  do nothing
}

public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count, final int after)
{
    //  do nothing
}

private final Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg)
    {
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) MultiTouchTest.this.autoCompleteView.getAdapter();
        final String[] urls = msg.getData().getStringArray("urls");
        for (final String url : urls)
        {
            adapter.add(url);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

};

}
```

The code is not tested and I don't know, how to retrieve the URL suggest.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. The AutoCompleteTextView element is exactly what I've searched for. I found google's "Custom Search API" (http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) and the deprecated "Google Web Search API" (http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/) which could be used to implement an adapter. Unfortunately Google limits the number of requests per day. Having done some research I do not think that there is any adequate free and unlimited service.